# Determine if a sql request returns zero records in asp.net application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I have an asp.net application which requests my database, everything is working, but I would just like to know how can I know from the oracle reader the number of requests found by the request.

This is my code :

```
            OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            string sql = "SELECT MYTABLE.MYFIELD FROM MYTABLE";                
            command.CommandText = sql;
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            // 
            while (reader.Read())
            {

            }
```

Does the reader have a propriety showing the number of records found from the request?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959511/row-count-from-oracledatareader

Comment: In general, a query may start returning rows before it is known how many total rows will be returned. The only way to know how many rows the query will return is to accept all of the rows.

Comment: Datasets have this, because they put the entire result in memory. In my opinion your best option is to do a `Count(Id)` of the same query first, as a scalar operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I had already found the solution of the counter, but I was thinking that it was possible to know immediatly the number of rows founded and not to have to execute the reader at each time.

Comment: Rather than first executing a `count` of the query and then executing the same query again, it is also possible to retrieve the row count as a column in the query using analytic count like `SELECT MYTABLE.MYFIELD, COUNT(*) OVER () NUMROWS FROM MYTABLE`. *Note:* If there is zero rows, your reader will not read any rows so you will never get NUMROWS=0. *Note 2:* Oracle now has to read through the entire result before sending rows to your reader, so it will be slower before your reader starts getting first rows, but then can be faster getting to the end. Total time probably unchanged.

Comment: Thanks Silvermind, the count(id) solution seems to be appropriated. But how can I get the result of this request from my oracledatareader?

Comment: Basicaly, I have a table of users, and I juste need to know if a specific user is recorded in the table. So probably juste a select count will be enough

Comment: I cannot get the result of my select count from the oracledatareader, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You would have to use `ExecuteScalar`